# How to add the object names in a dict based on their type in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have several objects e.g.,

```
obj_1 = class(obj_type, "name_1", stereotype = "type_1")
obj_2 = class(obj_type, "name_2", stereotype = "type_2")
...
```

and I would like to create a dict with the names as keys and the stereotypes as values:

```
{obj_1: type_1, obj_2: type_2}
```

Comment: Can you put the class definition?

Answer (score 0):

Use package [python-varname](https://github.com/pwwang/python-varname)

```
from varname import nameof

output = {}

obj_1 = class(obj_type, "name_1", stereotype = "type_1")
obj_2 = class(obj_type, "name_2", stereotype = "type_2")

output[nameof(obj1)] = obj1.stereotype
output[nameof(obj2)] = obj2.stereotype

print(output)
```